# Update a variable of an object within a List within a Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a program for my local football team. I have added new players to an Array List and this ArrayList is in a map. The map contains 5 different teams my club has. Each player is then put in an ArrayList for the team they play for. I now need to be able to increment the games played by each player.

I currently have a method `addGame` which takes 2 arguments, a String for the team name and a String for the playerName. In the Player class I have methods to increment the games a play has played `addAGame` this simply increments the gamesPlayer variable by 1. I will also eventually do the same for goalScored, assists etc.

My current method looks like this,

```
public void addGame(String team, String playerName){

//create a new List which will hold all the players from the team specified
List<Player> teamsA = teams.get(team);
```

This is where I am now stuck on how to amend the variable in the Player class.

I have a getter method for `gamesPlayed` which returns gamesPlayed. I was thinking this would work,

```
playerName.getGamesPlayer().addAGame();
```

My logic being that I would get the `int` value for gamesPlayed referenced to playerName and then run the addAGame method to increase it by 1...

I am not sure what else to try to get it to change the value associated with that player.

Comment: Have you tried the approach that you described?

Comment: try `for(Players playerName: teamsA) { playerName.getGamesPlayer().addAGame();}`
But of course you structure needs to have that structure which you described.

Comment: add the posible solution that you mentioned

Comment: @kelgwiin I have tried that and it says cannot find the method getGamesPlayer(). I am not sure I am referencing the Player object correctly

Comment: It looks like you may be looking for something like `for (Player p : teamsA){ if(p.getName().equals(playerName){ p.setGames(p.getNames()+1); } }`